# enumerate entity children

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to create a method that will take Linq-to-sql entity and return a list of all it's children(only 1st generation) entitysets, without any data that entitysets contain, just names. Is there any way I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question correctly, you can inspect the meta-model for a data context instance. The meta-model describes the tables, columns and associations in your model. Basically you want to look at associations on a table where the association is 1-to-many.

This doesn't involve retrieving any data, as you are not actually working with entity instances, just the information that describes them.

This code should do it:

```
public static string[] GetChildEntities<T>(DataContext context, T entity)
{
   var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));
   return mapping.RowType.Associations.Where(a => a.IsMany)
                                      .Select(a => a.ThisMember.Name).ToArray();
}
```

This will return the names of any properties that expose the `EntitySet` instances for the given parent entity.

**EDIT**

This code finds the first 1->* association between the parent and child entities based on the meta-model, retrieves the value of the EntitySet property on the parent entity, and adds the child entity to that set. This should work for most basic LINQ to SQL implementations.

```
public static void AddChild<P, C>(DataContext context, P parent, C child) 
    where P : class
    where C : class
{
    var parentMapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(P));
    var childAssociation = 
             parentMapping.RowType.Associations
                     .Where(a => a.IsMany && a.OtherType.Type == typeof(C))
                     .FirstOrDefault();

    if (childAssociation != null)
    {
        var entitySet = (EntitySet<C>) childAssociation.ThisMember
                                                       .MemberAccessor
                                                       .GetBoxedValue(parent);
        entitySet.Add(child);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, thanks for pointing in that direction. My goal is to create a method that will take both child entity and parent, cast "ThisMember" to appropriate entityset and add a child to there, whatever type that is. Can you help me with that? Your method is definitely a right step.

Comment: This method works even with disconnected entities, thanks so much